# Average visited interval for different people

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'visited': ['2015-3-4', '2015-3-5','2015-3-6','2016-3-4', '2016-3-6', '2016-3-8'],'name':['John','John','John','Mary','Mary','Mary']})
df['visited']=pd.to_datetime(df['visited'])
```

```
       visited  name
0   2015-03-01  John
1   2015-03-05  John
2   2015-03-06  John
3   2016-03-04  Mary
4   2016-03-06  Mary
5   2016-03-08  Mary
```

I wish to calculate the average visited interval by dayfor two people, in this example, the outcome should be

```
  avg_visited_interval  name
0                    1  John
1                    2  Mary
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) together with `diff` and `mean` like this:

```
df.groupby('name')['visited'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean()).to_frame('avg_visited_interval')
```

Result:

```
name    avg_visited_interval
John                  1 days
Mary                  2 days
```

The `avg_visited_interval` column here will be in datetime type. To make the column an int (i.e., number of days) you can add `dt.days` between `diff()` and `mean()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with lambda function for difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), last use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.groupby('name')['visited']
        .agg(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.mean())
        .reset_index(name='avg_visited_interval'))
print (df)
   name  avg_visited_interval
0  John                   1.0
1  Mary                   2.0
```

Last if necessary change ordering of columns:

```
df = df[['avg_visited_interval','name']]
print (df)
   avg_visited_interval  name
0                   1.0  John
1                   2.0  Mary
```